# Converting ActionScript 3 FLA’s to HTML5 canvas FLA’s in Flash cs6

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, html5-canvas, flash-cs6

**Hi there,**
i have doubt about converting **.fla** files to **html5 canvas**. i am developing the project by using **Action script version 3** but now i want that project on **html5 canvas** for the browser compatibility and other issues to be solved..

Anyone help me to solve the issue

I am trying **Swiffy Extension** and **CreateJS** tools. But the code was not linking properly because am using action script and also i don't know how to linking files from one to another.. please anyone help me to solve the issues.

**Example .FLA code:**

```
package com.privacy_pirates.game  {

    //import all the Flash libraries we will need
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{
        //all the onjects that are on the stage that will need to be called
        public var content_mc:MovieClip;
        public var introLoader:Loader;
        public var tutotrialLoader:Loader;
        public var preloader_mc:Preloader;
        public var btn_play:MovieClip;

        public function Main() {
            // constructor code
            //when the class is added to the stage
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
        }

        public function addedToStage(e:Event):void{
            //trace("added to stage is executing");
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
            //the swf that will be loaded
            introLoader = new Loader();
            //when it's ready, perform the function loadComplete
            introLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
            //make the preloader
            introLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);   
            //the file that will be loaded
            introLoader.load(new URLRequest("Animation.swf"));
        }

        private function loadComplete(e:Event):void{
            //trace("load is complete");
            //add the file to the stage
            addChild(introLoader);
        }

        //the progress bar at the bottom of the screen
        private function loadProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void{
            var percent:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal;
            preloader_mc.setPercent(percent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Those tools are best for coverting visual assets (animations etc) but even their help documents insist you have to rewrite the functionality of the AS3 code (where possible) with JavaScript IDE. Anyway check **[this link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/createjs/articles/getting-started.html)** and also **[this one](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/createjs/articles/using-flash-pro-toolkit-createjs.html)** for JS code tips in Flash timeline. So forget linking AS code and redo in JS what you need. If you learnt AS3 for the above code why cant you learn JS for similar result?

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for the support.if i try to study all the javascript functionality, it will take more time to solve. In my AS3 code has more than 5000 lines and also not familiar in javascript...                                                       Anyway i will try to solve that issue with your support.. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting CreateJS lib assets for use with require.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106453/exporting-createjs-lib-assets-for-use-with-require-js)